# Solving and plotting a linear initial value problem

Tags: differential-equations, homework

As my first Mathematica assignment, I need to solve and then plot a linear IVP. I understand that I must use `DSolve`. However, when attempting to plot my output, nothing shows.

My equation is

$\qquad x\,y'+ 2 \cos(x^2)\,y = 0 \quad  y(1) = 2$

I understand that this is not a very difficult problem, but I am struggling to understand the Mathematica way of expressing the problem.

Comment: It is hard to help without exact code. General tips: check individual elements, check the built in documentation. If you click on any function once and press F1 you will see the documentation. Mathematica is case sensitive and `Cos` and `cos` are not the same thing. Start with very simple things, like `Solve` and only then try more complicated code.

Answer (score 4):

There is a certain amount of syntax to be learnt.  Note that we must make the dependence of `y` upon `x` explicit

```
equation = x y'[x] + 2 Cos[x^2] y[x] == 0;

initialvalue = y[1] == 2;
```

It is convenient to return the solution as a pure function

```
solution = DSolve[{equation, initialvalue}, y, x]
(* {{y -> Function[{x}, 2 E^(CosIntegral[1] - CosIntegral[x^2])]}} *)
```

This makes it easy to verify that it is indeed a solution and satisfies the initial condition.

```
equation /. solution
(* {True} *)

initialvalue /. solution
(* {True} *)
```

I suggest that you work through this example, looking for help (`F1`) on all the functions and syntax elements that you don't know already.

To see the result, you can use

```
Plot[y[x] /. solution, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}]
```

Comment: When I try to plot the solution of this, nothing appears on my graph. I'm using Plot[solution[x_], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}] at the moment. What is my issue?

Comment: solution is a rule enclosed in a list that is also enclosed in a list. Mikado's answer shows that it is `{{y -> Function[{x}, 2 E^(CosIntegral[1] - CosIntegral[x^2])]}}`. You can plot it the way Mikado demonstrated but the closes to the way you wrote it is to replace `solution[x_]` with `solution[[1,1,2]][x]`. That is: `Plot[solution[[1, 1, 2]][x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}]`